# C# UniqueId class XML deserialization

Tags: c#, xml, deserialization

I'm trying to deserialize `urn:uuid:a0a32a4f-9687-46ef-bdc7-e4ab049ac56f` from XML file. Sample of my document is

```xml
<Document>
  <Name>Billy</Name>
  <TheId>urn:uuid:a0a32a4f-9687-46ef-bdc7-e4ab049ac56f</TheId>
</Document>
```

I'm trying to deserialize into the following class

```cs
public class Document
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public UniqueId TheId { get; set; }
}
```

My full demo code:

```cs
[Serializable]
public class Document
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public UniqueId TheId { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string Xml = @"
            <Document>
                <Name>Billy</Name>
                <TheId>urn:uuid:a0a32a4f-9687-46ef-bdc7-e4ab049ac56f</TheId>
            </Document>
        ";

        XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(Xml));
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Document));
        Document doc = (Document)serializer.Deserialize(reader);

        Console.WriteLine("Name is: {0}", doc.Name);
        Console.WriteLine("Id is: {0}", doc.TheId);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

But every time I got new uniquid instead of the value stored in the XML document.

What I'm doing wrong?

UPD:
`UniqueId` class is located into the System.Runtime.Serialization assembly

My final goal is to get this value into `Guid`, which I suppose to do with `UniqueId::TryGetGuid`.

Comment: It is located in `System.Runtime.Serialization` assembly. May it cause the problem?

Comment: @xanatos - [it is very much a .net type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.uniqueid?view=netframework-4.7.1)

Comment: I could reproduce this (Core 2.0). This is a good mcve question by the way.

Comment: I'm surprised, you would expect a type from `System.Xml` to be XmlSerizalizable. But it won't write either.

Comment: @xanatos: Hmmm.... I can still reproduce this with 4.7.1 ....

Comment: @xanatos 4.7.0, 4.7.2 - still reproduces

Comment: @AleksandrGorbach My problem... The `UniqueId` is created by the deserializer but the value is not set, is it is a random guid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple solution:

```
public class Document
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
    [XmlElement("TheId")]
    public string TheIdString { get => TheId.ToString(); set => TheId = new UniqueId(value); }

    [XmlIgnore]
    public UniqueId TheId { get; set; }
}
```

Add a different `string` property that will be serialized/deserialized, and make its backing "field" the `UniqueId TheId` (I think it is the adapter pattern but not sure).

By taking a look at the source code of [`UniqueId`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Runtime.Serialization/System/Xml/UniqueID.cs) I don't see special handling for `XmlSerializer`, like a `IXmlSerializable` interface. Nor is there any documentation about it being compatible with `XmlSerializer`.

Ah... The `[EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]` is so that you aren't suggested the `uniqueIdImpl` property by the Intellisense.

Comment: Thank you, I've considered this solution before asking the question. Your implementation is neater than mine. But I'm really curious, why this happens for `UniqueId` class!

Comment: @AleksandrGorbach It is supported from `XmlReader`, but probably they (Microsoft programmers) didn't ever thought of supporting it directly in `XmlSerializer` Without direct support by `XmlSerializer`, the `UniqueId` would need "manual" support that should be implemented by `UniqueId`. No such support exists.